# Problema ao inserir dados no BD com PDO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, banco-de-dados

Meu erro:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\atTheClub\adm\classes\casas.php on line 36

Arquivos:

casas.php



`class casas extends Crud{

protected $table = 'casas';
private $nomeCasa;
private $pessoaContatoCasa;
private $telefoneCasa;
private $emailCasa;
private $enderecoCasa;

public function setNomeCasa($nomeCasa){
    $this->nomeCasa= $nomeCasa;
}

public function setPessoaContatoCasa($pessoaContatoCasa){
    $this->pessoaContatoCasa = $pessoaContatoCasa;
}

public function setTelefoneCasa($telefoneCasa){
    $this->telefoneCasa= $telefoneCasa;
}

public function setEmailCasa($emailCasa){
    $this->emailCasa= $emailCasa;
}

public function setEnderecoCasa($enderecoCasa){
    $this->enderecoCasa= $enderecoCasa;
}   

public function insert(){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table (nomeCasa, pessoaContatoCasa, telefoneCasa, emailCasa, enderecoCasa) VALUES (:nomeCasa, :pessoaContatoCasa, :telefoneCasa, :emailCasa, :enderecoCasa)";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nomeCasa', $this->nomeCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pessoaContatoCasa', $this->pessoaContatoCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':telefoneCasa', $this->telefoneCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':emailCasa', $this->emailCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':enderecoCasa', $this->enderecoCasa);
    return $stmt->execute();
}


}`

crud.php

`require 'db.php';
abstract class Crud extends DB{
    protected $table;
    abstract public function insert();
    abstract public function update($idCasa);
}`

Apaguei as funções de delete e buscar para diminuir o trecho de códigos.

E abaixo o arquivo onde encontra-se a classe DB que o PHP diz que está o erro:

db.php


`require 'config.php';
class DB extends PDO{
    private static $instance;
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                self::$instance->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        };
        return self::$instance;
    };
    public static function prepare($sql){
        return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    };
};`

Então, primeiro eu não tinha estendido a classe PDO à classe BD, pensei que isto resolveria, testei e gerou o mesmo erro, caso alguém souber o que está acontecendo, agradeço muito! 
Apaguei todas as verificações, deixei somente o que supostamente precisaria para inserir os dados.

Comment: Para já note que está usando *Singleton*, e outra coisa é, que quando você herda da classe `PDO` não mais há necessidade de usar o `new PDO(...)`, podes simplesmente usar `parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $opcoes)`, e muito facilmente você poderia usar `parent::prepare` em vez do que aí tens. Se houver tempo e ainda não for resolvido o problema, analiso melhor o teu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua classe que realiza a conexão tá um pouco confusa, acho que não há necessidade de estendê-la a classe PDO pois, PDO é uma classe nativa do php, também não há necessidade da função static prepare(). tente deixar sua classe mais simples talvez;

```
class BD{   
    /**
     * [$pdo será objeto com a conexão]
     * @var [obj]
     */
    private static $pdo; 
    /**
     * [$host Host]
     * @var string
     */
    private static $host = 'seu_host';
    /**
     * [$name nome do banco]
     * @var string
     */
    private static $name = 'seu_banco';
    /**
     * [$charset charset utilizado no banco]
     * @var string
     */
    private static $charset = 'utf8';
    /**
     * [$user usuário do banco]
     * @var string
     */
    private static $user = 'usuario_do_banco';
    /**
     * [$passwd senha do banco]
     * @var string
     */
    private static $passwd = 'senha_do_usuario_do_banco';

    /**
     * [__construct Construtor da classe]
     */
    private function __construct(){}   

    /**
    * [getInstance Verifica se existe uma instância da conexão, caso nao exista retorna uma nova.]
    * @return [obj] [retorna objeto da conexão]
    */
    public static function getInstance() {   
        if (!isset(self::$pdo)):  
            try {   
                $opcoes = array();   
                self::$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=" .self::$host. "; dbname=" . self::$name . "; charset=" . self::$charset . ";", self::$user, self::$passwd, $opcoes);   
                self::$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
            } catch (PDOException $e) {   
                print "Erro com a conexão: " . $e->getMessage();   
            }   
        endif;   
        return self::$pdo;   
    }       
}
```

Já na sua classe *casas.php* você pode criar um objeto privado chamado $pdo para ser instânciado no construtor da classe ficando disponivel como objeto da conexão para todas suas funções na classe.

```
require 'db.php';

protected $table = 'casas';
private $nomeCasa;
private $pessoaContatoCasa;
private $telefoneCasa;
private $emailCasa;
private $enderecoCasa;
private $pdo; // Será nossa conexão na classe

function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = BD::getInstance();// instancia conexão
    }

public function setNomeCasa($nomeCasa){
    $this->nomeCasa= $nomeCasa;
}

public function setPessoaContatoCasa($pessoaContatoCasa){
    $this->pessoaContatoCasa = $pessoaContatoCasa;
}

public function setTelefoneCasa($telefoneCasa){
    $this->telefoneCasa= $telefoneCasa;
}

public function setEmailCasa($emailCasa){
    $this->emailCasa= $emailCasa;
}

public function setEnderecoCasa($enderecoCasa){
    $this->enderecoCasa= $enderecoCasa;
}   

public function insert(){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->table} (nomeCasa, pessoaContatoCasa, telefoneCasa, emailCasa, enderecoCasa) VALUES (:nomeCasa, :pessoaContatoCasa, :telefoneCasa, :emailCasa, :enderecoCasa)";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':nomeCasa', $this->nomeCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pessoaContatoCasa', $this->pessoaContatoCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':telefoneCasa', $this->telefoneCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':emailCasa', $this->emailCasa);
    $stmt->bindParam(':enderecoCasa', $this->enderecoCasa);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para executar um método de uma classe pai utilize o operador `parent`

```
$stmt = parent::prepare($sql);
```

Comment: Utilizei desta forma, mas mesmo assim não deu certo. Tá estranho isso :/

<code>
public function insert(){

  $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table (nomeCasa) VALUES (:nomeCasa)";
  $stmt = parent::prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nomeCasa', $this->nomeCasa);
         return $stmt->execute();
 }
</code>